# Prevent header from email when sending from swift mailer in symfony

Tags: php, email, symfony, swiftmailer

Am using swift mailer to send email.It is working fine but in email it is sending the header information.How can I prevent it to send header information in email.It is like:

```
 HTTP/1.0 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Thu, 10 Jul 2014 14:42:58 GMT
 Hello User

 Here is your email content
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to use `renderView()` instead of `render()`

`renderView()` returns the content of the view.

`render()` returns the Responseobject.

as the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#rendering-templates) says